# Grid 5x5 and 14 filled cells, prove some will be toching

Tags: graph-theory

Given 5x5 grid and 14 filled cells in it. Prove that some 2 of filled cells will have a side-side contact.
The question is simple to state, but i didn't manage to find the solution.

Clearly, there is no way to fill more than 13 cells on 5x5 grid, so that filled cells are not adjacent.

Comment: Hint: Find 12 pairs neighboring cells, with 1 left over. Apply Pigeonhole Principle to conclude that ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can rephrase this problem in terms of a graph and graph coloring. Let $G$ be the graph formed by letting the vertex $v_i$ correspond to one of the cells of this grid. There is an edge between vertices $v_i$ and $v_j$ if the corresponding cells share a side.

Now ask about the colorability of this graph $G$. So we wish this graph to be 2-colorable and this is equivalent to your original question. If $G$ is 2-colorable, then it must generate a bipartite graph with independent sets $X,Y$. Since these sets are independent, the size of the largest of these sets is given by
$\left \lceil \dfrac{25}{2} \right \rceil = 13$.

This lets us conclude that we can only color this graph with two colors if we color a maximum of $13$ vertices one of the colors.